# Google chrome extension between Mac and PC

Tags: google-chrome, google

I'm using Google Chrome both on my macbookpro and my pc.

On my PC which running IDM extension on Google Chrome. But on my Mac i really don't need that.

So my question is: how can i use google chrome on mac without IDM extension? I'd like to keep my bookmark.

Comment: Can't you simply sign in to Chrome, sync everything and then delete the extension on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

1. Log in to your Google Account on Chrome (top right)
2. Choose the sync everything you want (including extensions)
3. If everything is synched, go to settings (`Cmd` + `,`) and under synchronisation settings uncheck extensions
4. Remove the IDM extension

Make sure you have synch set up on your PC as well